# NSNotification-based iOS App

Tags: ios, delegates, model, nsnotification

I am currently thinking about the data-model for my iOS App. The app does only receive Information from a server and therefore, the "model" itself generally does all the web-requests, ...
However, these network requests have to be performed in the background - I mean another task, not the iOS background state - and after the request has finished, the information in the Application has to be updated.

Would it make more sense to write a delegate to inform the controller or could I also use NSNotificationCenter? I think an NSNotification-based solution could make the model more universal, e.g. in a desktop application.
And maybe, I should add: the model (since it saves some session Information) is a singleton, so a regular delegate based method would not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that it would be a good idea to use a separate thread to handle the communication. Apart from being complex, it is not necessary since `NSURLConnection/NSURLRequest` do allow you to handle communication asynchronously, i.e., without blocking.

In detail, you can create an [NSURLRequest](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html) executing:

```
NSURLRequest* yourReq = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:yourURL];
```

then create an [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) with:

```
NSURLConnection* yourConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:yourReq delegate:yourDelegate];
```

and start it with:

```
[yourConnection start];
```

When the data is ready, one of the methods for your delegate (`connectionDidFinishLoading:`, or `connection:didFailWithError:`) will be called so that you can update your UI.

All this without blocking.

An even better alternative to using `NSURLConnection/NSURLRequest`, is using [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/), which seems to be more resilient as to memory management and also offers a great caching mechanism.

EDIT: if your concern is that being your model a singleton, you cannot have a delegate, let me suggest that you look further into the matter.

Your model may be a singleton and the delegate to your request may have nothing to do with the model, apart from knowing how to access it (which is pretty trivial being the model a singleton).

This is possible by several mechanisms with `NSURLConnection`, but if you use `ASIHTTPRequest`, it will become really easy, because each `ASIHTTRequest` can have its own delegate.

Comment: Thanks, I am actually using the NSURlConnection like this at the moment :D this ASIHTTPRequest thing looks really amazing since I am also downloading big files in my app...

Comment: You should always handle the communication in a separate thread or the UI will freeze for the duration of the communication. The only question is if you spawn the thread yourself or if you let an API do it for you.

Comment: @chrischw_de I too can recommend ASIHTTPRequest.

Comment: @Erik B: asynchronous I/O is handled by the OS through interrupts. This defeats the necessity of using threads to avoid blocking. Non blocking behavior is inherent to interrupts. Here you have more details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O#Signals_.28interrupts.29

Comment: @chrischw_de: if you think that you cannot use the delegate because your model is a singleton, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

A delegate solution does work and is recommended. It looks something like:

```
[[DataLayer sharedInstance] fetchDataWithDelegate:self];
```

That method can spawn a background thread and respond to the delegate on the main thread.

Comment: OK, thanks. But in general, it is not wrong to make such kind of model a Singleton, right?

Comment: In almost every app I've worked with we've used a singleton class as the entry point to the data layer. I don't think there's anything wrong with that. I do know that some people consider singleton to be a bad thing in general, but I don't see a problem with it.